# Update JSF messages after initial rendering via p:menuitem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Does anyone know if it's possible to update a JSF message or messages element AFTER its initial rendering via PrimeFaces' p:menuitem?

For example, I have a PrimeFaces p:menuitem I am using to open a p:dialog, and that p:dialog has a p:messages element whose message I would like to update and show the moment that the p:dialog is opened - I can't know whether there is a message I want to show or what that message should be until after the p:menuitem's action method is complete.

Unfortunately, setting the update attribute of the p:menuitem to both the id of the p:dialog and the id of the p:messages element itself does not cause the p:messages element to show its message, even though I think it should since the action method of the p:menuitem looks like it is properly adding a message to the p:messages element.

The menuitem opening the dialog:

```
<p:menuitem value="Show Dialog with Message" action="#{myView.prepareDialogWithMessage()}" oncomplete="PF('dialogWidget').show()" update="dialogWithMessage message" />
```

The dialog with the message:

```
<p:dialog id="dialogWithMessage" widgetVar="dialogWidget" resizable="false" dynamic="true" closable="false" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:messages id="message" for="message" showDetail="true" escape="false" autoUpdate="true"/>
    <div class="button-panel">
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" action="#{myView.submitAction()}" oncomplete="PF('dialogWidget').hide();"/>
        <p:commandButton value="No" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" onclick="PF('dialogWidget').hide();"/>
    </div>
</p:dialog>
```

The Java code which adds the message:

```
public void prepareDialogWithMessage() {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Summary of message we want to show when the dialog opens", "Details of the message we want to show when the dialog opens");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("message", message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Kukeltje, however I believe that both the p:message and p:messages component do not have a javascript API because 1) I cannot find any mention of it in the PrimeFaces docs and 2) neither component has a widgetVar attribute therefore I don't believe there is any ID you could pass in to PF(widgetVar) for accessing any undocumented javascript API

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje, however our application's design/architecture is such that we avoid (as much as possible) writing any raw HTML or JavaScript. In this case it feels like the update attribute on the p:menuitem should cause the p:messages element to be updated after the p:menuitem's action is complete - that would seem to be the expected/documented behavior. So I am trying to understand where I may have misunderstood the expected/documented behavior before I consider other workarounds like the one you have suggested.

Comment: I appreciate the time you spent looking at this @Kukeltje and have followed your lead and removed my comment about any offense taken. Also, I updated this question once I understood the problem better - I don't think my original phrasing "update JSF messages BEFORE form submission" was correct since I found another page in our application which does update JSF messages before form submission using the page's preRenderView method.

Comment: Read about the dynamic attribute on the dialog. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Removing/changing the value thatis

Comment: The dynamic attribute of p:dialog "enables lazy loading of the content with ajax" and therefore I believe it has to be set to true since we don't want the content of the p:dialog to be loaded until something like my p:menuitem calls a backing bean to specify what messages the p:dialog should show

Comment: I'm writing answer... I hope you are not going to be offended ;-)

Comment: I won't be offended at all, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Short answer***: It behaves exactly as expected and implemented.

***Longer answer***:

Having a closer look after your edited question, I noticed the `dynamic="true"` on the dialog. If you read the PrimeFaces docs it states (as you already found out):

> dynamic: Enables lazy loading of the content with ajax.

So when you show the dialog via javascript, its ***content*** is updated... Since this content also includes the `p:messages`, that is also updated. In your case updated ***again*** with the messages that are generated in the ajax call of the update of the dialog... Most likely none... So the messages you added to it in the `prepareDialogWithMessage()` call of the `menuItem` are lost.

Since you already update the dialog in the call to the menuItem, the `dynamic='true'` is totally superfluous and it throws a spanner in the works.

<off-topic>A suggestion is to always start creating an [mcve]. Removing more and more until the behaviour of certain parts is as expected. Removing the `dynamic='true'` in one of the steps would have resulted in this and you'd have known a lot more. At the same time, also try debugging more. Investigating by looking at the requests and responses in the browser developer tool. You would have seen the messages getting added to the dialog and then the dialog(contents) being totally overridden. All these things are easy too (sorry, easy instead of 'not to difficult), can/will tell you a lot and helps getting to the cause of things quicker. Either directly, or by being able to ask way more specific question that is often easier to answer</off-topic>

Comment: The tone is still not quite positive or nice - some of your word choices and phrasing makes it feel like you are belittling me - but I appreciate the answer

Comment: Well, English not being my native tongue could be part of the cause, but... In many questions in StackOverflow (at least in JSF, PrimeFaces, but also css, jquery, javascript, ajax etc) too little effort is taken before posting questions. Searching for duplicates is part one of them, but that is often caused by looking at problems from a to high level (end-user-perspective even in many cases). 'How can I create show cities when I select a country' when the actual problem is related to to selectOneMenu's.

Comment: And to little is invested in creating a real [mcve]. Removing more and more and finding the real cause or getting very close. Very often to little is debugged and even simple things like looking at the network traffic and drawing conclusions or at least ruling out things is also not conducted, or trying newer versions, or looking into releasenotes, issuelists etc... And instead of giving people fish, I'd like to learn them how to fish. I tried that here to by hinting at the dynamic attribute, but you did not try, you just replied with your asumptions.

Comment: I could have boldly stated: try (or please try?), but you'd been offended then too. So I answerd and added some explicit things how to approach things in the future. Believe me, it helps when you do that. People here that are helping, appreciate that a lot since it reduces their time needed to find the cause, and the things we want to do least are stating to improve questions over and over again. So spending a little more time up front reduces your time waiting for an answer or hints. So you may feel the way you feel, but I hope you think of this writing your next question ;-)... Peace, cheers

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje. I agree with everything you said. That's why I debugged this on my own - including my colleagues along the way - for 8+ hours before posting a question here. This shows that I am not as skilled or knowledgable as you at debugging PrimeFaces/JSF issues and I was fortunate that you came across this question and solved it for me. All I ask is for you to adjust your attitude and consider that many times questions are posed by people whose expertise is not as sharp as your own, and you do not need to belittle them for that.